# Get File Name from Standard SaveAs Dialog

Tags: excel, vba

How Can we get the user inserted FileName in the standard SaveAs dialog, which any user can access from the File menu?
I am using the Workbook_Beforesave event to catch the user action, and identify the SaveAs by testing the SaveasUI parameter, but the event does not return the user selected file name.

This should be really simple, but I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance for any help!

My final objetive is to force File Saving of active workbook to always be in .xlsm format.

Comment: `My final objetive is to force File Saving of active workbook to always be in .xlsm format` Well, `Workbook_BeforeSave` cannot capture that. And `Workbook_AfterSave` will be too late to handle it. You can disable the "File SaveAs" using `Workbook_BeforeSave` event and then show your own dialog box using `Application.GetSaveAsFilename`. This way you will be able to force the `Save As` as per your requirement.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply.

Comment: When the user selects SaveAs from the File Menu, chooses a filename and Clicks Save. Then I catch it with beforesave, and display again a dialogbox with GetSaveAsfilename. But then the users enter the filename twice. The first input is lost/discarded because I cannot get it. (or don't know how to..) Users complain about the duplicate introduction of the filename. This didn't happen in old Excels (2003) because Beforesave would trigger just after selecting the saveas option in the menu. Any ideia to overcome the duplicate introduction of the filename?

Comment: The `Workbook_BeforeSave` event will fire the moment you click on File Save As and not after the dailog is shown or when you click on 'Ok' Button of that dialog box

Comment: I Just tested in a blank workbook. The BeforeSave event did not fire upon selection of the SaveAs option on the File menu. It only fired upon clicking on the Save button shown on the SaveAs screen to the right of the file format selection (drop down). If it fired upon selecting the SaveAs option in the menu then problem solved. Is there a BeforeSaveAs event?